# Install libxcb on Windows bash subsystem

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am trying to cross compile Qt using the Windows bash subsystem. In order to do that, I need to install some packages. One of the packages I need is the `libxcb-*` packages. However, when I try to install it, I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package libxcb-util-dev
E: Unable to locate package libxcb-util1
```

I am guessing I need to add something to my `sources.list` file. The `sources.list` in the Windows bash looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

What do I need to add to ensure that I can install the `xcb` packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Trusty` you can `apt-get` `xcb`, or if you want the developer stuff `libx11-xcb-dev` .
See here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libx11-xcb-dev

You can use the search feature there for these kinds of questions.